# How to patch value in angular with dynamic fields?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object of values in angular and I want to add that object to my formGroup. But somehow I am unable to do that. Please check my code and let me know where I am wrong.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.socialMediaForm = this.fb.group({
      //---------------------//
      //   Add values here  //
      //-------------------//
      socialAccounts: this.fb.array([]),
    });

    const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_info'));

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(userInfo)) {
      this.socialMediaForm.patchValue({ [key]: value });
    }
  }
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need add the FormControls to your form. For this, you need use the method [addControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl)

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(userInfo)) {
    const control=this.socialMediaForm.get(key)
    if (!control) //if not has a control called "key"
        this.socialMediaForm.addControl(key,new FormControl(value))
    else
        control.setValue(value);
}
```

If you're sure that has no control you can simply

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(userInfo)) {
    this.socialMediaForm.addControl(key,new FormControl(value))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add values from an object to a form then you need to create another nested FormGroup variable inside your main FormGroup.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.socialMediaForm = this.fb.group({
      userInfo : this.fb.group({}),
      socialAccounts: this.fb.array([]),
    });

    const userInfoFromStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_info'));

    this.socialMediaForm.patchValue({userInfo:userInfoFromStorage});

  }
```